# Module to manage lots of blocks

Tags: blocks

Any module to manage lots of blocks?
Since the block page is so huge to load.
Or any other methods to manage lots of custom user defined content expect node.

Comment: Could you please explain your use case? If you use different sets of blocks on different pages I might have a good answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the [Context](http://drupal.org/project/context) module.

> Context allows you to manage contextual conditions and reactions for different portions of your site. You can think of each context as representing a "section" of your site. For each context, you can choose the conditions that trigger this context to be active and choose different aspects of Drupal that should react to this active context.
>
> Think of conditions as a set of rules that are checked during page load to see what context is active. Any reactions that are associated with active contexts are then fired.

Answer (score 0):

The block admin page is not supposed to be loaded in daily activities. Don't worry about it. If a huge draggable table make that page impossible to use, then disable JavaScript when you are on it.